# Replacing the parentheses in a string

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting response from the server like this "[ 61 ]" I want to get rid of the parentheses and keep the numbers only.

This is what I did, but this does not work for dynamic responses, it only fits static number, but if the number gets bigger, this doesn't work

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(response);

    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb.deleteCharAt(7);
    numberofvotes.setText("Counts : " + sb.toString().trim());
}
```

How can I remove parentheses anywhere in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep only the number, you can use [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which use regular expression like this :

```
//response = "[ 61 ]";
response.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""); // Output '61'
```

Which mean replace all non digits.

Or like [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087276/replace-parentheses-in-string-in-android#comment85180222_49087288) mention you can use :

```
response.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Comment: BTW this kind of negation also exist with other predefined character sets. For instance `\s` vs `\S`, or even ones in form `\p{name}` vs `\P{name}`.